# Flask: one template does not extend base correctly

Tags: python, html, templates, flask

One of my templates (**offers_overview.html**) does not inherit my **base.html** template correctly. Instead it just outputs the html given in *offers_overview.html* without the html from *base.html*.

I have another template (**customer_overview.html**) with the exact same html as offers_overview.html and it extends the base.html perfectly fine. That is what makes me confused. **What am I doing wrong?**

Here is what my views.py looks like for *offers_overview*:

```
@mod.route('/<username>/<int:inquiry_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def show_offers_overview(username, inquiry_id):
 user = Customers.query.filter_by(cusername=username).first()
 inquiry = Inquiry.query.filter_by(iid=inquiry_id).first()

 if (user or inquiry) is None:
    flash('User %s or inquiry %s is not found.' % (username, inquiry_id))
    return redirect(url_for('user.user_overview', username=user.cusername))
 return render_template('offers_overview.html', inquiry=inquiry)
```

Here is what views.py looks like for *customer_overview*:

```
@mod.route('/<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user_overview(username):
 user = Customers.query.filter_by(cusername=username).first()
 if user is None:
    flash('User %s not found.' % username)
    return redirect('/user/login')
 return render_template('customer_overview.html', customer=user)
```

Here is offers_overview.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Offers overview{% endblock title %}
{% block body %}
  <h2>Not important {{ inquiry.worktitle }}</h2>
  <br>
  <h3>Future</h3>
  <br>
  <h3>Present</h3>
  <br>
  <h3>Past</h3>
{% endblock body %}
```

Which is exactly the same code as in customer_overview.html, except from inquiry being changed to customer.

I tried changing which template to be rendered in *show_offers_overview()* to customer_overview. The result was that the child template did not inherit the base template.

**UPDATE**
This is how the templates are structured:

```
|project\
   |app\
      |templates\
         |--base.html
      |user\
         |templates\
            |--customer_overview.html
            |--offers_overview.html
         |--__init__.py
         |--views.py
```

Comment: are all of these 3 html templates in same directory?

Comment: No, base is in the "global" template directory. The others are in the blueprint specific template directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in my base.html I had code that made deeper pages not inheritate the static file *off-canvas.css*. For example page

```
localhost:5000/user/myusername
```

would work, but not

```
localhost:5000/user/myusername/123
```

It looked like this in base.html where I refered to the css static file:

```
<link href="../static/off-canvas.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I had to change to url_for in base.html, see here:

```
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='off-canvas.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```